# Order SQL query on best match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I get a list of results returned from my query that I want to order on the best match. I will try to be as clear as I can be, but if something is not clear enough, let me know and I will try and make it more clear.

A user has already entered a list of settings, called `findsettings`. With these `findsettings` I am searching for products. This all goes well, until he should go sort out the best match.

There are several fields such as `min_review, max_price, allows_pets, etc`.

I want to order on. For example he needs to order first on products with a `min_review of 40%`, then `max_price = 10.00` and then `allows_pets = 0`. You can do that with an `OR`, but I want the results that don't quiet match also to show, only at the bottom of the list. So basically he should show the best match first, then the 2nd one, the 3rd one etc., until the products that matches the least.

I'm not sure how to handle this, so I hope you can help me sort that out.

Comment: Can you show us your table structure, indices and query code? It sounds like you want to use a FULLTEXT index and utilize MATCH AGAINST, but without seeing structure and code it is hard to tell you the best approach.

Comment: Please include a full example, with multiple records in the order you'd like. For example, if the search includes "Min Review of 40%", should a review of "99%" come before or after a review of "41%"? I would infact suggest that the order criteria and the search criteria should be separate: `MinReview=40%, MinPrice=10.00 ; Price ASC, Review DESC` *(I changed this to MinPrice on purpose, for the next example)*. When including records that don't quite match, ***exactly*** what do you want? Should `40%, 9.99` come before or after `39%, 10.00`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic principle is to create a relevance score for each record and then sort by that.

Where you want each criterion to have equal weight, in MySQL you can just add each boolean expression together (note that this is non-standard SQL—in other RDBMS you may have to use `CASE` to test the condition and yield a number):

```sql
ORDER BY (review>=40/100) + (price<=10.00) + (allows_pets=0) DESC
```

If the criteria are not equally weighted, you can either multiply each expression by its weight:

```sql
ORDER BY 5*(review>=40/100) + 3*(price<=10.00) + 1*(allows_pets=0) DESC
```

And/or if those that match on some subset should *always* appear first irrespective of the later results, you can divide your `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY 5*(review>=40/100) + 3*(price<=10.00) DESC,
         1*(allows_pets=0) DESC
```

Should you want to see the relevance score in your results, you can similarly add any of the above expressions to your `SELECT` (and then use the resulting column in your `ORDER BY` clause so as to avoid writing it twice):

```sql
SELECT   *,
         (review>=40/100) + (price<=10.00) + (allows_pets=0) AS relevance,
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Note that should you want to obtain records which have a value closest to some target (e.g. `min_review` close to 40%, rather than exact), you can take the (absolute?) difference between it and your target value:

```sql
IF(review>=40/100, review-40/100, NULL)
```

However, you must be careful to weight your expressions appropriately if/when combining with others in a single criterion.

Comment: A distance score has the problem that the Op says that *anything* on the wrong side of the boundary should appear after *everything* on the right side of the boundary. So, for the condition `MaxPrice=10.00` will have `Price=10.01` after *every* record with a price from `10.00` and lower, even down to a price of `0.01`. It also doesn't account for order preference - saying `MaxPrice=10.00` doesn't actually tell you if the searcher prefers `Price=0.01` or if they prefer `Price=9.99`. These are useful components to use in a final algorithm, but not *(in my opinion)* a final answer or approach.

Comment: This solution (at least the first `order by` clause) *does* put all matches above partial matches.  I think this answers the question.