# PHP/MySQL make top 10 out of selection

Tags: php, mysql, select

A user can input it's preferences to find other users.
Now based on that input, I'd like to get the top 10 best matches to the preferences.

What I thought is:

1) Create a select statement that resolves users preferences

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sex FROM ledenvoorkeuren WHERE userid = you"))
$stmt->bind_result($ownsex);
```

2) Create a select statement that checks all users except for yourself

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sex FROM ledenvoorkeuren WHERE userid <> you"))
$stmt->bind_result($othersex);
```

3) Match select statement 1 with select statement 2

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $match = 0;
                if ($ownsex == $othersex) {
                    $match = $match + 10;
                }
// check next preference
```

4) Start with a variable with value 0, if preference matches -> variable + 10%

Problem is, I can do this for all members, but how can I then select the top 10???
I think I need to do this in the SQL statement, but I have no idea how...

Ofcourse this is one just one preference and a super simple version of my code, but you'll get the idea. There are like 15 preference settings.

// EDIT //

I would also like to see how much the match rating is on screen!

Comment: Actually, I don't get the idea - because you're assuming I know something about your application and therefore your problem. Please be more descriptive about what it is you're trying to build

Comment: Ok, so you log in and want to find other people.
To do this, you give in preferences, like sex, age, province etc...

Then, based on these preferences, you should see a top 10 with people that most match your preferences.

Comment: Out of the entire database of people? Or a smaller set?

Comment: See [Order SQL query on best match](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13342536), then add a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal, gonna check out that article...looks like something similar as I want :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was a good question from the start so I upvoted it and then wasted about 1 hour to produce the following :)

**Data**

I have used a DB named `test` and table named `t` for our experiment here.

Below you can find a screenshot showing this table's structure (3 `int` columns, 1 `char(1)` column) and complete data

[image: source table with data]

As you can see, everything is rather simple - we have a 4 columns, with `id` serving as primary key, and a few records (rows).

**What we want to achieve**

We want to be able to select a limited set of rows from this table based upon some complex criteria, involving comparison of several column's values against needed parameters.

**Solution**

I've decided to create a function for this. SQL statement follows:

```
use test;

drop function if exists calcMatch;

delimiter //

create function calcMatch (recordId int, neededQty int, neededSex char(1)) returns int
begin
    declare selectedQty int;
    declare selectedSex char(1);

    declare matchValue int;
    set matchValue = 0;

    select qty, sex into selectedQty, selectedSex from t where id = recordId;

    if selectedQty = neededQty then
        set matchValue = matchValue + 10;
    end if;

    if selectedSex = neededSex then
        set matchValue = matchValue + 10;
    end if;

    return matchValue;
end//
delimiter ;
```

**Minor explanation**

Function calculates how well one particular record matches the specified set of parameters, returning an `int` value as a result. The bigger the value - the better the match.

Function accepts 3 parameters:

- recordId - id of the record for which we need to calculate the result(match value)
- neededQty - needed quantity. if the record's qty matches it, the result will be increased
- neededSex - needed sex value, if the record's sex matches it, the result will be increased

Function selects via `id` specified record from the table, initializes the resulting match value with 0, then makes a comparison of each required columns against needed value. In case of successful comparison the return value is increased by 10.

**Live test**

[image: live test of the function]

So, hopefully this solves your problem. Feel free to use this for your own project, add needed parameters to function and compare them against needed columns in your table.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `limit` and `offset` in query:

```
SELECT sex FROM ledenvoorkeuren WHERE userid = you limit 10 offset 0
```

This will give the 10 users data of top most.

Comment: LIMIT 10 does give max 10 users yes.
And offset gives users 1-10.

But how do I do the matching part. So, how do I check witch people matches the users preferences the most?

Comment: @Nick On what basis you where match the users preference? can you let me know. well you can add your preferences in the where clause.

Comment: Don't really get your question.
But I want something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342035/order-sql-query-on-best-match/13342536#13342536

Gonna try if I can manage to get that working

Comment: Don't know how I can post that here in a simple way.
But I'll try the link first.

Thanks for your answer so far, I may get back to you :P

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit in your query like this:

```
SELECT sex FROM ledenvoorkeuren WHERE userid <> yourid AND sex <> yourpreferredsex limit 0, 10
```

Where the '0' is the offset, and the '10' your limit

More info [here](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
SELECT sex FROM ledenvoorkeuren WHERE userid = you limit 0, 10 order by YOUR_PREFERENCE
```

Comment: Uhm, I get the idea, but how can I really order by 15 preferences?
Got any example...cause I can't see it working yet.

And how would that give me a match %?